# IOS CoreData fetch duplicates on each view load

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new to CoreData, and I'm having some difficulty getting it to work.

The problem I'm having is on each time my view controller loads, the data fetched from core data is getting duplicated.

for example:

- There is only 1 object in Entity named Order
- There are 2 view controllers on main view, and another is order view

1. First time segue push from the main view to order view, order view shows 1 order (Normal)
2. Go back from order view to main view
3. Second time segue push from the main view to order view, order view
   shows 2 orders (Duplicate)
4. Again, go back from order view to main view
5. Third time enter order view, order view shows 4 orders (next time
   would be 8 an so on)
6. Exit app, and enter again it's back to 1 order

I don't know why every time the fetch method is called, it returns duplicated objects

OrderViewController

```swift
var dataSource = [FailedOrderEntity](){
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource=self
        tableView.delegate=self
        fetchFailedOrders()
}

func fetchFailedOrders(){
        dataSource.removeAll()
        dataSource = failedOrderCoreData.fetchAll()
}

//Other are all table related
```

FailedOrderCoreData

```swift
class FailedOrderCoreData {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context = NSManagedObjectContext()
    let entityName = "FailedOrderEntity"

    init() {
        context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func fetchAll() -> [FailedOrderEntity] {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        var fetched: [FailedOrderEntity] = []
        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(request)
            if !results.isEmpty {
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                    //breakpoint: 1st time call result returns 1, 2nd returns 2, 3rd returns 4, 4th returns 8..so on
                    let order = FailedOrderEntity(context: context)
                    order.order_id = result.value(forKey: "order_id") as? Int32 ?? 0
                    fetched.append(order)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("ERROR: Could not fetch orders")
        }
        return fetched
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because you create new data in your loop with this code

```
let order = FailedOrderEntity(context: context)
```

to fetch data with entity class model use this code

```
var fetched: [FailedOrderEntity] = []
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FailedOrderEntity> = FailedOrderEntity.fetchRequest()
do{
    try fetched = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch {}
```

Comment: thanks man. So turns out I don't need all those statements to fetch. this is much easier.

Comment: yup, i dont know why most tutorial did not use this simplest way to fetch data